# Why is used WHICH can mean_ but WHAT usually meanS

Tags: grammar, syntax

In my textbook in paragraph "Who, What and Which" I have seen:

- WHICH can mean_ a person or a thing (bottom line is mine)
- WHO always mean**S**  a person
- WHAT usually mean**S** a thing

Question:
Why is there used "can mean" but "always\usually mean**S**" ?

I think the cause is word "can" but I don't know how to explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verbs can be finite (tensed) or non-finite.  Examples of finite verbs are "went", "goes".  Examples of non-finite verbs are "to go", "gone".  Infinitives and participles are non-finite.

A word like "go" is finite when it represents the present tense ("I go"), but non-finite when it is an infinitive, which can be a bare infinitive without "to" ("I can go", "I can be", "I will do", "she would have").

Auxiliary verbs are followed by non-finite forms.

Modal auxiliaries such as "can", "will", "could", "would", "may", "might", "shall", "should", "must" are followed by *bare infinitives*.  The bare infinitive is identical in form to the present tense (except for "be" and except for the 3rd person singular), so another way of saying it is that modals are followed by the *plain form* of the verb.  So we say "she must know", "he must see", "it must be" - not <strike>"she must knows", "he must sees", "it must is"</strike>.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks for your kindness.